# XSL Transform - Filepath with spaces

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to execute an XSL transform to convert a CSV file to XML using Java and Saxon.

```
<xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($pathToCSV)">
```

I am calling the command like this:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin>java.exe -jar c:\saxon\saxon9he.jar -o:"E:\Temp\Folder Has Spaces\test.xml" -it:main -xsl:E:\Temp\csvxml_TEST.xsl pathToCSV="E:\Temp\Folder Has Spaces\test.csv"

The script works fine if they input path does not include spaces.
Is there a way to make this script work when there are spaces in the input path?

Full XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="fn"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="pathToCSV" />

<xsl:function name="fn:getTokens" as="xs:string+">
    <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="concat($str, ',')" regex='(("[^"]*")+|[^,]*),'>
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence select='replace(regex-group(1), "^""|""$|("")""", "$1")'/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/" name="main">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($pathToCSV)">
            <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text(pathToCSV)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, '&#xa;')" as="xs:string+"/>
            <xsl:variable name="elemNames" select="fn:getTokens($lines[1])" as="xs:string+"/>
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="$lines[position() > 1]">
                    <row>
                        <xsl:variable name="lineItems" select="fn:getTokens(.)" as="xs:string+"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$elemNames">
                            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                            <elem name="{.}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($lineItems[$pos])"/>
                            </elem>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>Cannot locate : </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$pathToCSV"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How/where does it fail exactly, in the command line shell, in the XSLT code? Which error do you get? If you get the string with spaces used as a parameter in XSLT it might be safer to use `unparsed-text(concat('file:///', || replace(replace($pathToCSV, '\\', '/'), ' ', '%20')))`.

Comment: Or perhaps `unparsed-text(iri-to-uri(concat('file:///', replace($pathToCSV, '\\', '/'))))` suffices.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've used this "unparsed-text(concat('file:///', replace(replace($pathToCSV, '\\', '/'), ' ', '%20')))" which has now worked! Thank you!

Comment: Fine, I morphed the suggestions from the comments with your correction into an answer so that you can mark the question as being solved by accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most XPath and XSLT functions work with URIs and not with system/os dependent file paths so you might try to convert your Windows file path to a URI with e.g.

```
unparsed-text(concat('file:///', replace(replace($pathToCSV, '\\', '/'), ' ', '%20')))
```

or

```
unparsed-text(iri-to-uri(concat('file:///', replace($pathToCSV, '\\', '/'))))
```

Note that the EXPath file module supported in Saxon PE and EE (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/functions/expath-file/path-to-uri.html) has method `file:path-to-uri`: http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.path-to-uri.

Comment: Alternatively, pass in a URI as the parameter value so it doesn't need to be converted.