# Saxon, XSLT: processing thousands of xml files in a complex tree structure

Tags: python, xml, xslt, saxon

I use a python script that iterates through thousands of xml files in a complex tree structure and execute the following Saxon command:

```
java -cp C:\saxon\SaxonHE10-6J\saxon-he-10.6.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:{input} -xsl:{xslt} -o:{output}
```

My final output is one txt file ; each line corresponds to one xml file and is a selection of xml element values from it.

This is working well but the performance is very low. I suppose it is because my python script calls the Saxon command each time a new xml file in my iteration is processed.

What would be the right approach to speeding up the process, if possible drastically?

Kind regards.

Excerpt from the python file:

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderXmlSource):

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            input = '"\\\\?\\' + str(os.path.join(root, file)) + '"'
            output = '"' + os.path.join(folderTxtTemp, file[:-4] + '.txt') + '"'
            try:
                transform(input, output)
                print(input, 'jjjjj', output)
                finalize(output)
            except:
                errorLog.write(input + '\n')
```

The `transform` function calls Saxon and processes the XSLT transformation. The `finalize` function concatenates in the final result file all the results obtained from the XSLT transformation of each xml file.

Excerpt from the XSL file:

```
<!--  //System:FileName  -->

    <xsl:variable name="System:FileName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//System:FileName">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="//System:FileName !=''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//System:FileName"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>System:FileName VIDE</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>System:FileName ABSENT</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

The XSL file looks for specific elements like, for instance, `System:FileName`. If this element exists, it puts the value of it in a variable. All the variable contents that are obtained from the different elements are then concatenated into a txt file.

Comment: Well, firing up the Java VM for each of thousands transformations is certainly not an efficient way; so the question is whether you want to write Java code with Saxon Java to have single Java program run that does all the transformations or whether you want to use SaxonC (https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/) with a Python program. There might also be a way using a single XSLT but using `uri-collection` to process a collection of input documents, to help you with that we would need to see more details on what kind of iteration through thousands of file you currently do.

Comment: I do not want to write Java code. I do not know SaxonC, could be interesting. My priority would go to using `uri-collection` (or `collection`?). My iteration uses an xsl file that selects some element values ; if an element is empty or missing, the output is something like 'missing element' or 'empty element'. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: I would recommend to use SaxonC from Python and not to start call a Java program, the documentation for SaxonC 12 is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html. As for `uri-collection`, as I said, we need to see the current Python and XSLT code to tell whether that is an option. Is that the same XSLT code run an all input samples? How do you currently ensure (with several calls doing java net.sf.saxon.Transform) that you end up with a single result text file?

Comment: The same XSLT code runs on every xml file. To end up with a single result text file, my python script copies the result of each saxon txt output (one per xml file) into the final result text file.

Comment: I would prefer to see some code, both of the Python program as well as of the XSLT; you can edit your question and add code samples there. I don't know how longish your real code is, I hope it is not too long or you can try to show the essential parts.

Comment: You can use it as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77914230/how-to-merge-two-similar-xml-files-using-xslt/77914788#77914788

Comment: @MartinHonnen : I had some code in my question. I hope it helps. Your help is welcome.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the paths, why is that input constructed as `input = '"\\\\?\\' + str(os.path.join(root, file)) + '"'`, is that an UNC path on Windows?

Comment: Adding the prefix `\\\\?\\` prevents from the problem of having too long paths. More exactly: with this prefix, I do not get an error when the path is too long. I do not remember where I found this trick, but it works well. I am on Windows, yes.

Comment: Does the Python code do anything other than iterate over files and invoke the XSLT transformation on each one? If so, you can scrap the Python layer entirely and just run the whole thing as a single XSLT transformation from the command line, in which case it makes very little difference whether you use SaxonC or SaxonJ.

Comment: Note that with the single-XSLT approach you will get a massive saving from not initializing the Java VM repeatedly, and if you use Saxon-EE you will get an additional benefit because the Saxon collection() function will process multiple input files in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try to use SaxonC 12 (e.g. use the PyPi package saxonche) and change the Python code to e.g.

```
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor

def transform(saxon_proc, xslt30_executable, input, output):
    xdm_input = saxon_proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name=input)
    xslt30_executable.set_global_context_item(xdm_item=xdm_input)
    xslt30_executable.apply_templates_returning_file(xdm_value=xdm_input, output_file=output)


with PySaxonProcessor() as saxon_proc:
    xslt30_processor = saxon_proc.new_xslt30_processor()
    xslt30_executable = xslt30_processor.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file='yourXsltStylesheet.xsl')

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            input = '"\\\\?\\' + str(os.path.join(root, file)) + '"'
            output = '"' + os.path.join(folderTxtTemp, file[:-4] + '.txt') + '"'
            try:
                transform(saxon_proc, xslt30_executable, input, output)
                print(input, 'jjjjj', output)
                finalize(output)
            except:
                errorLog.write(input + '\n')`
```

See whether that alone not already gives a drastic performance improvement.

You can then also consider to use multithreading with Python and SaxonC, as done in https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonC12ThreadPoolExecutorXSLTTransformation, to further improve performance.

I will look at the XSLT and whether it is possible to delegate all to a single XSLT next.

Comment: This is very interesting. I will give your proposal a try and give news. Also interested by the 'single XSLT option', if you can.

Comment: First try, @Martin. Very promising in terms of performance. However, I got this error: `saxonche.PySaxonApiError: Unable to resolve <long_path\Recette 1 accÃ©lÃ©rer\CurrentVersion.xml> into a Source. Line number: -1`. I suppose it is a character encoding problem ('accélérer'). Would you have any suggestion to solve it?

Comment: @silfer1200, I suppose that is in input file path? Can you give me a full example, it is both spaces and accented characters in a folder/directory name? Anyway, sometimes, with SaxonC and Python, for me it has helped to use the pathlib module  `from pathlib import Path` and use e.g. `Path(yourpath).as_uri()` as the value passed to SaxonC from Python for an input or result file/URI.

Comment: I did some test with a folder containing spaces and (German) umlaut characters, SaxonC 12.4.2 consumes something like `Path(f'umlaut test ä ü ö', f'{file_name}').absolute().as_uri()` as the `xml_file_name`, without giving such an unable to resolver into a Source error. `Path` is e.g. from `from pathlib import Path`.

Comment: I even get something like `xml_file_name=Path(f'umlaut test ä ü ö\{file_name}').absolute().as_uri()` to be processed so Windows path separators (i.e. `\` instead of `/`) should work.

Comment: I'm on the verge of accepting this solution, but I still have a blocking problem. `xml_file_name=Path(f'umlaut test ä ü ö\{file_name}').absolute().as_uri()` or let say `Path(f'{root}\{file}').absolute().as_uri()` is absolutely fine for accepting folder names including characters like `ä, é, ê`, but not file names. A file name like `Rhône_prev_jpg.xml` gives an error from Saxon. I would be grateful for an input.

Comment: Well, either start a new question with the necessary details or at least tell me exactly (might be difficult in a comment) which error you get (for SaxonC 12? but not for Saxon Java 12?).

Comment: For me e.g. `xdm_doc = saxon_proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name=Path(f'Rhône_prev_jpg.xml').absolute().as_uri())` works, if I don't use the `Path(..).absolute().as_uri()` I get the previous error unable to resolve as source but with that Python path/uri helper Saxon processes the file name/uri.

Comment: Saxon produces an output file with name `RhÃ´ne_prev_jpg.txt` instead of `Rhône_prev_jpg.txt`. So, then, I have a Python `FileNotFoundError` when my script tries to find the output file to make something else with it. I have just spotted this.

Comment: So the problem now is with an output file name. Is the name used/generated inside XSLT with e.g. `xsl:result-document href` or is it just used as the name for the primary result in the Python API (e.g. `apply_templates_returning_file(output_file=...`)?

Comment: I have from you the code `xslt30_executable.apply_templates_returning_file(xdm_value=xdm_input, output_file=output)`. The file generated has for name `RhÃ´ne_prev_jpg.txt`, and, instead of it, my Python script needs the name `Rhône_prev_jpg.txt`.

Comment: I will ask O'Neil from Saxonica to have a look.

Comment: I am currently not sure how to solve that, other than that I have tested if I run Python under the Linux subsytem for Windows (WSL) then Saxon and/or the OS manages to get that file name as `Rhône_prev_jpg` out. Not sure how make that happen with Windows Python.

Comment: I am grateful for your dedication. If you get any news from Saxonica about the issue, I will be interested. In the meantime, I will look for a way to bypass the problem (WSL or adapt my Python script).

Comment: I hope O'Neil will show up here somehow but it is Friday afternoon/evening so I can't tell when we will have time to look into this. And I don't know whether he will be able tell you how to adjust your Pyton and/or XSLT code or whether he needs to fix/improve output file handling for SaxonC under Windows, which will need a new release for you to be able to profit from that.

Comment: Matt from Saxonica here. Based on what both you and Martin have said, I thought this might be a bug in the way we handle unicode in filenames, but it works for me in a REPL on macOS. This makes me think that it's an issue with character encoding in your OS, for example if your python is interpreting UTF-8 file name strings as Windows-1252 (which is what that characteristic `accÃ©lÃ©rer` string looks like). However I'm not certain and I'll need to poke around on a Windows machine to make sure, but I probably won't be able to get to that until Monday morning...

Comment: Thanks for your patience. This is a bug in Saxon, which is only present on Windows. We're looking into exactly why. I've opened this issue on our tracker: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6353.

Answer (score 1):

As for using a single XSLT, you seem to look for all `.xml` files in a certain directory, that is what Saxon allows you to do also with a `file` URI to that directory and the URI query parameters `?select=*.xml;recurse=yes`, see https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/sourcedocs/collections/collection-directories.html.

So you would write a single XSLT taking a parameter for the source directory file URI e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="folder-uri" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">file:///C:/Users/foo/dir/subdir</xsl:param>
```

and then I would suggest to use the `uri-collection` function on that with e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:variable name="input-uris" select="uri-collection($folder-uri || '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$input-uris">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

then I would hope if you `xsl:import` your existing stylesheet into that main stylesheet and run it with `-it` from the command line without a source file (i.e. without the `-s:` option) or with e.g. `call_template_returning_file(output_file=output)` from the Python API, that it processes all input files and creates a single result file.

As for parsing or processing of individual files failing and trying to keep a record of that in a separate file, I think, with XSLT 3.0, you can use `xsl:iterate` over the `uri-collection` with a nested `xsl:try/xsl:catch` for that, a minimal example is in https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonC12IterateTryCatchTest, the XSLT is in https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonC12IterateTryCatchTest/blob/master/iterate-try-catch-test1.xsl and basically does e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="input-uris" select="uri-collection('input-samples?select=*.xml')"/>
    <xsl:iterate select="$input-uris">
      <xsl:param name="failed-uris" as="xs:anyURI*" select="()"/>
      <xsl:on-completion>
        <xsl:if test="not(empty($failed-uris))">
          <xsl:result-document href="failed-uris.txt" method="text" item-separator="&#10;">
            <xsl:sequence select="$failed-uris"/>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:on-completion>
      <xsl:try>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>
        <xsl:catch> 
          <xsl:next-iteration>
            <xsl:with-param name="failed-uris" select="$failed-uris, ."/>
          </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:catch>
      </xsl:try>
    </xsl:iterate>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the context of the previous suggestion with apply-templates you could therefore try e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:variable name="input-uris" select="uri-collection($folder-uri || '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
   <xsl:iterate select="$input-uris">
      <xsl:param name="failed-uris" as="xs:anyURI*" select="()"/>
      <xsl:on-completion>
        <xsl:if test="not(empty($failed-uris))">
          <xsl:result-document href="error-log.txt" method="text" item-separator="&#10;">
            <xsl:sequence select="$failed-uris"/>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:on-completion>
      <xsl:try>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>
        <xsl:catch> 
          <xsl:next-iteration>
            <xsl:with-param name="failed-uris" select="$failed-uris, ."/>
          </xsl:next-iteration>
        </xsl:catch>
      </xsl:try>
    </xsl:iterate>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax `doc(.)` in line `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>`. What does it refer to, please?

Comment: The `doc` function takes a URI argument and tries to load an XML document from that URI; the `uri-collection` function returns a sequence of URIs and that is processed by the `for-each` so that the context item inside is a single URI that is passed to the `doc` function, it loads the document and the `apply-templates` ensures that document tree is processed by your existing code (as long as you `xsl:import` it).

Comment: According to my first tests, this single-XSLT approach is also promising. My saxon command in a batch file is `java -cp path\saxon-pe-12.4.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it -xsl:%xsl_file% -o:%output_txt%`. Unfortunately, this command does not deal with transformation failures. In such cases, I need the source xml files to be listed in a txt file... and my saxon command to continue to run. What would be the equivalent of a python _Try/Except_ approach in the context of the command line or a batch file?

Comment: @silfer1200, I am sorry but I don't write batch files. So ask that as a separate question, adequately tagged (after searching in docs or existing questions doesn't turn up something). What kind of transformation failures do you have? XSLT 3 has `xsl:try/xsl:catch`.

Comment: I cannot answer your question at the time being. I tested your saxonche option on thousands of xml files, and it worked very efficiently. But saxon failed to process about 400 input xml files that are however listed in a txt file thanks to the python `Try/Except` approach. If `xsl:try/xsl:catch` was able to do something equivalent, that would be interesting.

Comment: It is hard to spell such things out here in comments but you could start by wrapping the `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>` into `<xsl:try><xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/><xsl:catch>..</xsl:catch></xsl:try>`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#try-catch. To collect all failures and write them to one file it might help to use `xsl:iterate` instead of `xsl:for-each`, that way you might be able to collect URIs of documents failing.

Comment: @silfer1200, I have edited the question and added some code sample to spell out the idea of using `xsl:iterate` together with `xsl:try/xsl:catch` to handle errors while processing  some of the input files and to create a separate result text file listing URIs where processing failed.

Comment: @silfer1200, are you still stuck? Or have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: stuck because of spaces in my URI `C:/Users/foo/dir/sub dir` in `<xsl:param name="folder-uri" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">file:///C:/Users/foo/dir/sub dir</xsl:param>`. I get an error like `The directory 'C:/Users/foo/dir/sub' does not exist`.

Comment: solved thanks to `file:path-to-uri` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61119536/xsl-transform-filepath-with-spaces)). Looking now for the opposite (uri to path) in order to get paths in `error-log.txt`.

Comment: Try to pass `iri-to-uri($uri)` to any functions in XSLT/XPath that expect a URI, that way a space should be properly percent encoded. Although note that a file URI would start with e.g. `file:///C:/Users/...` not with `C:/Users/...`. See also the comments on the other answer that in Python the pathlib library has a good way to convert file paths into URIs that Saxon can consume (e.g. `Path(f'sub dir').absolute().as_uri()`)

Comment: I cannot find a solution to get in the `error-log.txt` e.g. `C:\Users\name\Documents\xml_files\cd catalogs\test blue\camarade algèbre fre\no_xml_file.xml` instead of `file:/C:/Users/name/Documents/xml_files/cd%20catalogs/test%20blue/camarade%20algèbre%20fre/no_xml_file.xml`. I can live with it and turn to saxonche or saxoncpe, but I am a little frustrated.