# SaxonC-PE 12.4.2: trying to follow Saxonica setup instructions, but failing the installation test

Tags: installation, saxon, saxon-c

Trying to follow https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/installing/installingWindows, I made these steps:

1. Dezipped libsaxon-PEC-windows-x86_64-v12.4.2.zip into C:\Program Files\Saxonica\Saxon1242
2. Added C:\Program Files\Saxonica\Saxon1242\libs\win to the system environment variable "Path"
3. Added saxon-license.lic to C:\Program Files\Saxonica\Saxon1242\libs\win

Trying then to follow https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/running, I made these steps in cmd:

1. changed directory to C:\Program Files\Saxonica\Saxon1242\samples\cppTests
2. executed `build-windows.bat` - result: *'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command...*
3. executed `testXPath.exe` - result: *'testXPath.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command...*

My system: Windows 10, 64-bit

Your suggestions welcome. Kind regards.

Comment: You need MS C/C++ compiler/linker installed. I usually have that on machines where I have e.g. Visual Studio 2022 (Community edition is free) installed with "Desktop development for C++" workload. Then use the Visual Studio Native x64 tools command line prompt in administration mode (as you installed in `C:\Program Files`). Note there might be other ways without VS to install the MS C/C++ compiler/linker/tools but I can't point you to the minimum steps necessary to do that, perhaps someone else can help out. And the Python saxonche or saxoncpe package doesn't need VS or C/C++ compilation.

Comment: @Martin, refering to [question 77962974](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962974/saxon-xslt-processing-thousands-of-xml-files-in-a-complex-tree-structure/77963410?noredirect=1#comment137455028_77963410), my goal is to compare the saxonche solution (very efficient, but I am still getting character or path length problems that I need to analyze) and the so called 'single XSLT solution'. To test this one, thanks to your comment, I suppose now that I do not need SaxonC (and C/C++ compiler or Visual Studio 2022), but SaxonJ would be ok. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can run single XSLT from the SaxonJ command line with e.g. `-it -xsl:sheet.xsl`. You can also do it with saxonche or saxoncpe or saxoncee and Python code using e.g. `call_template_returning_file`. If you want to run SaxonC's command line tool `transform.exe`, however, you need to compile/build it first, and for that you would need MS C/C++ compiler/linker tools installed.